# Scala: Run function on only one member of a list

Tags: scala, list

I'm pretty new to Scala and am trying to run a function on only one member of a list. That is given a list that looks like

`val list = List("hi", "bye now", "see ya later")`

I would like to return a list that looks like

`val list = List("hi", "bye now", "see", "ya", "later")`

I know that if I run `list.map(_.split(" "))` I would get

`list = ("hi", "bye", "now", "see", "ya", "later")`. So, how do I do this using the lamdas without simply doing

`list.append(list(2).split(" "))` and `list.remove(list(2))`?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you only want to run a function on one element of a list, forcing use of `map` isn't the right answer. Your last way is probably the most straightforward.

Comment: Is this function of yours defined as "split the third element of the list", "split the element with highest length of the list", "split the element starting with 'see' ", "split the element that would result in most subelements" etc? Either one of those would gladly take your `list` and return the desired result, but you're not describing your problem well. Why do you need that particular element split? If it's simply "split the third element" then what you wrote in the last line seems completely fine.

Comment: You would have to run `flatMap` with `split`, not `map` to get list of strings after splitting everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're intent on applying a function only to specific entries in a list, you could:

```
list.zipWithIndex.flatMap {
  case (entry, idx) if (idx == 2) =>
    entry.split(" ")
  case (entry, idx) => List(entry)
}
```

This could be generalized a little more by going along the lines of:

```
// Add variance, curry, etc. as needed...
def flatMapOnly[A](list: List[A], offsets: Set[Int], f: A => Seq[A]): List[A] =
  list.zipWithIndex.flatMap {
    case (entry, idx) if (offsets.contains(idx)) =>
      f(entry)
    case (entry, _) => List(entry)
  }

scala> flatMapOnly(List("hi", "bye", "see ya later"), Set(1, 2), { str: String => str.split(" ").toList })
res39: List[String] = List(hi, bye, see, ya, later)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 list.flatMap { 
   case x@"see ya later" => x.split(" ")
   case x => Seq(x)
 }
```